# Вертикальный ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Как сделать чтобы `ViewPager` прокручивался вертикально?

Получится ли сделать первый фрагмент фиксированной высоты а последующие полноэкранные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких случаев есть `recyclerview`. Сделайте высоту item `match_parent`. Ну а если все таки именно viewpager нужен, то можно посмотреть сюда [viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/7104538)